# How do I centre this checkbox?

Tags: css

I have a table, one column of which contains only a checkbox and I am currently centering these with

```
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="xyz">
</td>
```

Now I want to add some JS to (de)select all/none, so I want to add a checkbox in my table header row, along with some text

TH is, by default, bold and I am happy leave it so for actual Column header text, bu I was normal text for the "all/none" and then I want a centered checkbox below that.

```
----------------  
| Search ?   | Next column  
| (all/none) |  
|   [x]      |
```

here's my code - how do I get that checkbox to center?

```
<th>Search?<br>    
    <span class="th_not_bold">(all/none)</span><br>    
    <input style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle" type="checkbox" name="search_all" id="search_all" onClick="ReportAllNoneClicked()">  
</th>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try using

```
<th> 
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
<div>Search</div>
    <div class="th_not_bold">(all/none)</div>
    <div><input style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle" type="checkbox" name="search_all" id="search_all" onClick="ReportAllNoneClicked()"> </div>
</td>
</th>
```

Comment: @Mawg - you should always try not to use inline CSS i showed it to u just because you wer using inline CSS. Try using a separate CSS always w3c also says so. makes the structure look more neat and clean

Answer (score 3):

You would do exactly the same thing you did for your other `<td>` - you would set `text-align center; vertical-align: middle;` on the `<th>`, and you wouldn't need to apply any properties to the checkbox:

[Here's an example of the code you'd use](http://jsfiddle.net/XXPT6/):

```
th{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use text-align:center. Here is what is looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/RcztD/1/

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style type="text/css">
    .center{
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th valign="top" class="center">
                Search?<br />    
                <span class="th_not_bold">(all/none)</span><br />    
                <input type="checkbox" name="search_all" id="search_all onClick="ReportAllNoneClicked()" />  
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```